# Capitalise month names in an array

Tags: php

How to get first character capital of each month in array or any other short method to achieve this?

```
$heading = array("apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec","jan","feb","mar");
foreach($heading as $key=> $month)
{
  echo  $heading[$key] = ucfirst($month);  //Apr, May,Jun It's ok
}
print_r($heading);
```

**Current Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => apr
    [1] => may
    [2] => jun
    [3] => jul
    [4] => aug
    [5] => sep
    [6] => oct
    [7] => nov
    [8] => dec
    [9] => jan
    [10] => feb
    [11] => mar
)
```

**Expected Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apr
    [1] => May
    [2] => Jun
    [3] => Jul
    [4] => Aug
    [5] => Sep
    [6] => Oct
    [7] => Nov
    [8] => Dec
    [9] => Jan
    [10] => Feb
    [11] => Mar
)
```

If I print `echo  $heading[$key] = ucfirst($month);` It display OK but any other short cut method?

Comment: `array_walk($heading, 'ucfirst');`

Comment: you defined `print_r($heading);` so it should be `array_walk($heading, 'ucfirst');`

Comment: Is `$heding` a typo? If not, then that should be `$heading`. Edit: So it was.

Comment: @Sadikhasan Yes, I saw your edit, which in turn I have modified my comment above after seeing it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can done in one line:

```
$heading = array_map('ucfirst', $heading);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $heading = array("apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec","jan","feb","mar");
    array_walk(
        $heading, 
        function(&$a) {
            $a = ucfirst($a);
        }
    );
    print_r($heading);

?>
```

Comment: @Sadikhasan It's pretty easy it goes though a callback function for every element in the array! (See the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Answer (score 1):

Update the original array, rather than output the value.

```
$heading = array("apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec","jan","feb","mar");
foreach($heading as $key=> $month)
{
  $heading[$key] = ucfirst($month);  //Apr, May,Jun It's ok
}
print_r($heading);
```

Also, you had a typo in the variable name, which might be causing you trouble. (Make sure to activate ALL forms of error reporting, so you catch these things)